# Get this "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server." Apache configuration or Laravel issue?

Tags: laravel, apache, virtualmin

I have a problem: after installing and setting up `https` my site stopped working.

I can only navigate to the index page. If I select login or create an account I get and error saying that the page doesn't exist:

> Not Found  The requested URL was not found on this server

I don't know if this is Apache's or Laravel's fault.

I am using Virtualmin, Ubuntu 20.4 lite, apache, and Laravel.
My directory on the server is `/home/domain/public_html/`. Under `public_html` I have my Laravel project with all the files and folders.

This are the setting used for Apache, config through virtualmin.

```
SuexecUserGroup "#1000" "#1000"
ServerName *mydomain*.se
ServerAlias www.*mydomain*.se
ServerAlias mail.*mydomain*.se
ServerAlias webmail.*mydomain*.se
ServerAlias admin.*mydomain*.se
DocumentRoot /home/*mydomain*/public_html/public
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/*mydomain*.se_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/*mydomain*.se_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/*mydomain*/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/*mydomain*/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php5 index.htm index.html
        
    
DocumentRoot "/home/*mydomain*/public_html/public"

<Directory "/home/*mydomain*/public_html/public">
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.4
    FCGIWrapper /home/*mydomain*/fcgi-bin/php7.4.fcgi .php
    FCGIWrapper /home/*mydomain*/fcgi-bin/php7.4.fcgi .php7.4
</Directory>
    
<Directory /home/*mydomain*/cgi-bin>
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
 </Directory>


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.*mydomain*.se
RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://*mydomain*.se:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.*mydomain*.se
RewriteRule ^(?!/.well-known)(.*) https://*mydomain*.se:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.4
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824

<Files awstats.pl>
    AuthName "*mydomain*.se statistics"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/*mydomain*/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>

Alias /dav "/home/*mydomain*/public_html/public"

<Location /dav>
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "*mydomain*.se"
    AuthUserFile /home/*mydomain*/etc/dav.digest.passwd
    Require valid-user
    ForceType text/plain
    Satisfy All
    RemoveHandler .php
    RemoveHandler .php7.4
    RewriteEngine off
</Location>

IPCCommTimeout 9999

<Directory "/home/*mydomain*/public_html/public/phpmyadmin">
</Directory>
```

Can someone please help me? I searched for answers on the forum and tested different settings but nothing works for me.